# Android, архитектура приложения, основанного на фрагментах

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Начинаю писать приложение, которое основано на очень понравишимся мне элементе `ViewPager`, собственно всё приложение и есть два экрана, на каждом этом элемент.

Получается так:

`SplashScreen` -> `Activity1` -> `Activity2`

`Activity1` держит на себе 2 фрагмента. Фрагменты и Activity содержат в себе инфу из db + retrofit запросы.

`Activity2` - держит уже 5 фрагментов. С любого фрагмнета можно перейти на `Activity1`, один из фрагментов умеет сейвить в db + отправлять retrofit запрросы.

В разработке я недавно, и из архитектурных решений знаю разве что MVP, и то в теории. Поэтому на большее чем выделить отдельный модуль для моделей меня ни на что не хватило пока.

Вопрос: как правильно построить это приложение? Использовать MVP?

На эти вопросы меня натолкнула мысль о том что в будущем я  столкнусь с проблемой тестирования этой махины и возможно с проблемой трансфера данных. Я понимаю что надо бы применить MVP, но 7 фрагментов в связке с MVP не умещаются у меня в голове(как и сама MVP к слову), не знаю как начать вообще.

UPD: если минусите, то пожалуйста, уточните в комментариях за что.